# Rounding a BigDecimal

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm trying to round a double value like this: 1.14593409534253205304203E-14
i dont know what the E-14 means...
I want it to be 1.1 . this is how I tried:

```
speed = (distanceupdate / 1000) / (milliseconds * 3600000);
speed2 = speed2 + speed; speed3++;

BigDecimal speed4 = new BigDecimal(speed).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
double speed5 = speed4.doubleValue();
```

I did it before for another value and it worked, but in this value is doesn't work.
I checked, value "speed" is not NULL, it always > 0 .
speed5 is always NULL =[

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a double equal to exactly 1.1.  A double has to be an inverse power of 2-  1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 or some combination thereof.  It can't be 1/10.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to an int while rounding then making it a double again

```
double speed = 1.14593409534253205304203 * Math.pow(10, -14); // equals 1.145934095342532E-14
int speedInt = (int) Math.round(speed * Math.pow(10, 15)); // equal 11
speed = speedInt / 10.0; // equals 1.1
```

Also, the E-14 part is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for 1.14593409534253205304203×10^−14.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. I edited my message, the value speed is about 1.123293242309234E-14  . i dont know what the E-14 means

Comment: Edited it to reflect the speed value of 1.123293242309234E-14

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your types are for the speed and such but with the exact value that you've specified I wrote this and got 1.1 as an answer.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       double speed = 1.14593409534253205304203;
       BigDecimal speed4 = new BigDecimal(speed).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
       double speed5 = speed4.doubleValue();
       System.out.println("Value : " + speed5);
   }
}
```

Output :

```
( ô_ô)σ : java Example
  Value : 1.1
```

And, yes `( ô_ô)σ` is my command prompt.

Comment: milliseconds is a long, distanceupdate is a double, speed1,speed2,speed4,speed5 = double

Comment: Try what @MrEngineer13 has done, that should work for you. And E is the [Exponential/Scientific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) notation that will help you write numbers that are too long/short to be written conveniently in a decimal form.